# r - data.table different behaviour with keys after merge and X[Y] joins

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the `data.table`s

```
library(data.table)   ## v1.9.7 (dev version)
#  rm(list=ls())
dt1 <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3),
                val=c(3,2,1))

dt2 <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3),
                val2=c(100,200,300))
```

Here, no keys have been assigned to the tables

```
tables()
#     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS    KEY
#[1,] dt1     3    2  1 id,val     
#[2,] dt2     3    2  1 id,val2    
#Total: 2MB
```

When using two different `data.table` join operations

```
dt_merge <- merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("id"))
dt_bracket <- dt1[ dt2, on=c("id")]
```

We see that the `merge` function has assigned a key but the `X[Y]` hasn't

```
#     NAME       NROW NCOL MB COLS        KEY
#[1,] dt_bracket    3    3  1 id,val,val2    
#[2,] dt_merge      3    3  1 id,val,val2 id 
#[3,] dt1           3    2  1 id,val         
#[4,] dt2           3    2  1 id,val2
```

If we then use two `data.tables` where the join columns have different names, it assigns the key as the X join column:

```
#  rm(list=ls())
dt1 <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3),
                val=c(3,2,1))

dt2 <- data.table(id2=c(1,2,3),
                val2=c(100,200,300))


dt_merge <- merge(dt1, dt2, by.x=c("id"), by.y=c("id2"))
dt_bracket <- dt1[ dt2, on=c(id = "id2")]
tables()
#     NAME       NROW NCOL MB COLS        KEY
#[1,] dt_bracket    3    3  1 id,val,val2    
#[2,] dt_merge      3    3  1 id,val,val2 id 
#[3,] dt1           3    2  1 id,val         
#[4,] dt2           3    2  1 id2,val2
```

I couldn't find an explanation in the [PDF FAQ - 1.12](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/FAQ) or [the CRAN documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) that explains why a key is assigned after a `merge`.

As this has just caught me out on a few `unique()` calls, I was wondering if this is this expected behaviour?

**Update - solution**

As Frank points out, the answer lies in the `sort` argument

```
dt_merge_sort <- merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("id"))
dt_merge_notSort <- merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("id"), sort=FALSE)

tables()

#     NAME             NROW NCOL MB COLS        KEY
#[1,] dt1                 3    2  1 id,val         
#[2,] dt2                 3    2  1 id,val2        
#[3,] dt_merge_notSort    3    3  1 id,val,val2    
#[4,] dt_merge_sort       3    3  1 id,val,val2 id
```

Comment: maybe because `merge` sorts data, key attribute is just a metadata about the ordering in dataset

Comment: @jangorecki I would suggest it's more than *just* metadata, as the key causes (albeit expected) consequences when calling functions such as `unique()`

Comment: It looks to me like `?merge.data.table` documents this for its `sort` argument: "If TRUE (default), the merged data.table is sorted by setting the key to the by / by.x columns. If FALSE, the result is not sorted."

Comment: @Frank looks good enough for an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like `?merge.data.table` documents this for its `sort` argument:

> If TRUE (default), the merged data.table is sorted by setting the key to the by / by.x columns. If FALSE, the result is not sorted.